# Can't execute my SQL Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Vet
(
     VET_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
     LAST_NAME CHAR(15),
     FIRST_NAME CHAR(15),
     STREET CHAR(15),
     CITY CHAR(15),
     STATE CHAR(3),
     POSTAL_CODE CHAR(5),
     SALARY DECIMAL(7,2),
     DEGREE CHAR(10),
     POSITION CHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO Vet (VET_NUM, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, STREET, CITY, STATE, POSTAL_CODE, SALARY, DEGREE, POSITION)
VALUES ('1', 'Skechley', 'Cristine', '24340 7th Plaza', 'Pittsburgh', 'PA', '15274', 88053.30, 'Masters', 'Vet'),
       ('2', 'Fishpoole', 'Sig', '06784 Anthes Point', 'Philadelphia', 'PA', '19184', 45525.56, 'Associates', 'Receptionist'),
       ('3', 'Stother', 'Rycca', '04304 Superior Hill', 'Allentown', 'PA', '18105', 90553.37, 'Masters', 'Vet'),
       ('4', 'Scandrite', 'Kerrill', '30320 Express Crossing', 'Harrisburg', 'PA', '17126', 102553.59, 'Doctorates', 'Vet'),
       ('5', 'Glassman', 'Rhett', '33418 Tomscot Trail', 'Mc Keesport', 'PA', '15134', 56052.24, 'Bachelor', 'Management'),
       ('6', 'Gioan', 'Rab', '1 Pennsylvania Street', 'Hatfield', 'PA', '19440', 35880.76, 'Student', 'Janitor');
```

The error I keep getting is

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 35
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Vet__7C53690AE94CBCDD'
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Vet'. The duplicate key value is (1 ).
>
> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 38
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 41
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 44
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me with this? I have looked on YouTube, and the video I watched said that the Data I have entered might not be good. I think my data is alright, but for some reason, I just can't get it to execute. I want to be able to see "Row has been effected"

Comment: Just a wild guess but you have a record with primary key = 1 and you are tying to add another record with primary key = 1. This often happens if you run the same script two times without erasing all the tuples between runs.

Comment: Another suggestion-- Why don't you change your PK to varchar. Like it should be `VET_NUM varchar(2) PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Nope dont have another row with primary key =1... this is confusing. I have every number different. Do you know whats up with all these "Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line ##
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated." Errors I am getting?

Comment: if you have over 99 records then your script will fail as your primary is char(2)... solution change table definition and let vet_num as integer and identity seeded ... in the insert statement remove the vet_num field and values.

Comment: In addition, some of the values you're inserting are larger than the size you've defined (see in particular the SALARY column - decimal points are part of the data as well as the digits). The best thing to do is exactly what the error message says - read the documentation about how to define columns. Also, why are you using CHAR(2) for a primary key instead of an autoincrement value?

Comment: Also: I'd **strongly recommend** not to use the `CHAR(n)` type too much - these columns will **always** be filled to defined length with spaces, e.g. you're **always** using 15 or 20 characters - even if you store just 1 character in that column. For "normal" strings, you should really use `VARCHAR(n)`  (which stores only as much as you really enter and doesn't unnecessarily pad your inputs with spaces!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE Vet
(VET_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_NAME CHAR(20),
FIRST_NAME CHAR(20),
STREET CHAR(30),
CITY CHAR(20),
STATE CHAR(20),
POSTAL_CODE CHAR(20),
SALARY DECIMAL(8,2),
DEGREE CHAR(20),
POSITION CHAR(20));
    INSERT INTO Vet(VET_NUM,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,STREET,CITY,STATE,POSTAL_CODE,SALARY,DEGREE,POSITION)
    VALUES
    ('1','Skechley','Cristine','24340 7th Plaza','Pittsburgh','PA','15274',88053.30,'Masters','Vet');
    INSERT INTO Vet
    VALUES
    ('2','Fishpoole','Sig','06784 Anthes Point','Philadelphia','PA','19184',45525.56,'Associates','Receptionist');
    INSERT INTO Vet
    VALUES
    ('3','Stother','Rycca','04304 Superior Hill','Allentown','PA','18105',90553.37,'Masters','Vet');
    INSERT INTO Vet
    VALUES
    ('4','Scandrite','Kerrill','30320 Express Crossing','Harrisburg','PA','17126',102553.59,'Doctorates','Vet');
    INSERT INTO Vet
    VALUES
    ('5','Glassman','Rhett','33418 Tomscot Trail','Mc Keesport','PA','15134',56052.24,'Bachelor','Management');
    INSERT INTO Vet
    VALUES
    ('6','Gioan','Rab','1 Pennsylvania Street' ,'Hatfield','PA','19440',35880.76,'Student','Janitor');
```

column length  is low